# What should be on-topic here?

Tags: discussion

What kinds of questions should be on-topic here?

(Sometimes this question works well in meta if we have one simple answer per reply, and then people can upvote and downvote each suggestion).

Comment: I think it would be of help if we have a sample of off-topic questions also.

Answer (score 6):

Questions about Korean grammar.

Answer (score 6):

Questions related to Korean language and language learning related questions that can be answered with some amount of objectivity, **even if there isn't a provable correct answer**, and even if the questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience. This is along the lines of sites like [parenting stack exchange](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/) which is another of the less 'scientific' sites.

[Should I learn Hangul when learning Korean?](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/9/should-i-learn-hangul-when-learning-korean) is an example of a question I think could usefully be on-topic for this reason.

This answer is *not* intended to include questions entirely based on opinions, like "What is the funniest Korean word" or similar.

Comment: I tend to agree here. While I **can** understand why my "Should I learn hangul?" question was closed as too opinion-based, I kind of feel like it is a useful question regardless.

Comment: @dotVezz I don't think it's opinion based as per the wording of the close reason - *answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions*. Clearly some personal experience comes into it but there are valid general points that can be made about language learning in general and hangul in particular.

Answer (score 6):

Questions about Korean pronunciation.

Comment: Although this tends to be challenging to approach when you're limited to text.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet is intended to be of help here!

Answer (score 6):

Cultural questions that are relevant to *learning* and *communicating* with the language.

Answer (score 5):

Questions about the meanings of Korean words.

Answer (score 4):

Cultural questions that are relevant to 'non-verbal communication' - for example how to hold your glass, body language, and so on.

Comment: I disagree with the down vote that has been given to this post. A language is not restricted to speaking & writing communication. However, I understand that questions should still be focused on the Korean language, and not the culture. (Or this should have been called *Korea*.)

Comment: It's hard to define criteria for a satisfactorily "on-topic" cultural question. That said, I feel it's important to find some way to do so; the [how do you count korean age](http://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/156/how-do-you-count-korean-age) question is a perfect example of a *cultural* question that is closely tied to *language*. When speaking korean and talking about one's age, an exceedingly common topic in Korean, it's important to know *how* to do so.

Comment: @dotVezz I guess that would be an example of a cultural question that is relevant to *verbal* communication - maybe that should be a separate answer here?

Comment: @topomorto oh yeah, you're right. I totally forgot this answer is for "non-verbal".