# Suggestions to fill in "What topics can I ask about here?" in our Help Center

Tags: discussion, help-center, on-off-topic

As you all know, Help Center will be a general guidance to all current and future users.

[What topics can I ask about here?](https://korean.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) in Help Center needs filling in. I think the linked question should be basis for our guidance on on-topic questions. [What should be on-topic here?](https://korean.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9/what-should-be-on-topic-here)

Japanese SE, [What topics can I ask about here?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

English Language and Usage SE, [What topics can I ask about here?](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Portuguese Language Beta SE, [What topics can I ask about here?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Portuguese SE is the newest language site on SE and I think it has an excellent page for on-topic questions.

I think we can get some ideas and start to draft it here until the page is completed. Any thought or suggestions?

Comment: It would still be nice to get some more input on this, but for now I've put up our most recent version on http://korean.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: @topomorto That's fantastic. I think it could be edited further when we have more points to add. I see nothing wrong with the current wordings. I just wonder who else will put more thought into this. Thanks.

Comment: The only thing I took out is "It’s also OK to ask and answer your own question". I can put it back if you like. The rest is all there.

Comment: I can't see that I can edit the order in the Help Center. I only edited the on-topic page itself...

Comment: I put the *own question* quote back in. Yep, I like close reasons to be helpful as possible - let's work out some good wordings at some point.

Comment: Re. deletion of comment - once two out of three moderators agree that a question is fair and on-topic, it's not fair to the question poster to leave a comment stating that it is not. That was my reasoning,  I don't think your "Please don't abuse your power" comment was called for - I am usually a friendly and constructive person to interact with and I'd appreciate it if good faith was assumed.

Comment: @topomorto Please ask yourself the following question when you decide to delete a comment or any other post. "Does it harm Korean SE in any way?" My comment didn't harm it. That's very obvious. Now, I don't care how many moderators agree or don't agree. If there is a moderator who doesn't even understand how SE works, my position gets firmer. You abused your power. My comment was intended for the OP to edit the post. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: Also, you need to note that a majority of the three moderators should not decide what can be asked and what can't be. The community should decide it. I am not insisting the question should be closed. I just cast my vote. But please think one more time before you cast your vote because you have effectively 5 votes yourself. Just because one of the moderators decided to answer an off-topic question doesn't mean the question is on-topic. There is much room to be improved. BTW, you won't be able to answer "beautiful, pretty, lovely, gorgeous" question on ELU or ELL because it will be closed.

Comment: 'Does it harm Korean SE in any way' *is* what I considered. I stated the (small but genuine) harm I saw in my previous comment - it's unfair to a poster to have the site's top user leaving comments in quite such an insistent tone about how they need to improve the question when the community has come to no such consensus. I realise that a comment explaining a close vote can be seen as a courtesy, and that there's perhaps a fine line there. But I did consider all that in good faith.

Comment: @topomorto [One question per post is the strict guideline of Stack Exchange.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post/222741#222741). Nobody challenges that as it is reasonable because Stack Exchange seeks to build a library of definitive answers. A question that can't generate a definitive answer should be put on hold until it is edited properly. A question that asks multiple questions in **one** post should be put on hold until the question is split into pieces. There are existing rules and guidelines which we don't have to have consensus on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Version 2

> ### What topics can I ask about here?
>
> - Word choice and usage, grammar, and pronunciation, including dialect differences
> - Korean linguistics, orthography (spelling, punctuation) or etymology
> - Specific problems encountered by people learning Korean
> - The meanings of words or expressions in context (if not clear from their dictionary definitions)
> - Questions on Korean culture that are relevant to language and communication
> - Help with usage of language in real-life contexts, such as asking about the meaning of a difficult Korean sentence, or how to express a
>     specific idea in idiomatic Korean
>
> Please make your question as clear as possible, with any necessary
>   **context, examples and references**, and any **research already done.**
>
> ### Is there anything I should not ask?
>
> **Please avoid the following types of questions**, which are outside the scope of this site:
>
> - Simple general reference questions and character recognition requests that can be answered by a resource such as a dictionary
>     (although requests for help and clarification *after* consulting a
>     resource may be acceptable)
> - Requests for translation and proofreading that contain no particular question about the Korean language
> - Questions about Korean Culture that do not concern the Korean language itself
> - Questions that ignore the advice on the [don't ask](https://korean.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) page
>
> ### Should I write in Korean or English?
>
> Both languages are accepted. When answering a question, we encourage you to answer in the language of the question, if you are able. Don't
>   worry about making a few mistakes: other community members can help
>   with corrections if you are not as strong in that language.
>
> All [tags](https://korean.stackexchange.com/tags) should be in English unless there is no English
>   equivalent for a concept; in those cases, Korean is accepted.

Comment: I've tried to 'condense' V1 - some of my changes will hopefully speak for themselves. Are there any changes that don't seem good? if so, I can explain in comments - or we can edit - or someone can do a V3!

Answer (score 1):

Please note that the Version 1 is based on [Portuguese SE's page](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Portuguese SE has two very well-experienced moderators who are moderating on English Language and Usage SE and Japanese SE respectively, too. Let me suggest my version first based on Portuguese SE's format. I think format-wise, Portuguese SE's version is more concise.

### **Version 1**

> **What topics can I ask about here?**
>
> The Korean Language Stack Exchange is for linguists, teachers,
> students, and anyone interested in the Korean language. Please make
> your question as clear as possible with an example sentence and proper
> context. Questions about the following topics are welcomed here:
>
> - Korean linguistics, orthography (spelling, punctuation) or etymology
> - Word choice and usage, grammar, and pronunciation, including dialect differences
> - The meaning of a word or expression in context (if it is not clear from the dictionary definition)
> - Problems encountered by people learning Korean
>
> But **please don't ask any questions about these topics**, which are
> outside of scope for this site:
>
> - Simple general reference question and character recognition request answerable by consulting a dictionary
> - Request for direct translation and proofreading without specific source of concern
> - How to improve your Korean
> - Questions that are primarily opinion-based including cultural questions not relevant to the Korean language.
> - Questions with too many possible answers, or that would require an extremely long answer
> - Criticism, discussion, and analysis of Korean literature
>
> A side note: We do ask that you look up the meaning of words or
> expressions in a dictionary first. If you can't find the answer you're
> looking for, go ahead and ask, but do provide the context and example
> sentence in which you found the word or expression, and tell us why
> you find the dictionary answer unsatisfactory.
>
> We are neither a translation nor proofreading service. Asking about
> the meaning of a difficult Korean sentence is fine. So is asking how
> to express an idea in idiomatic Korean. But please don't ask us to
> translate or proofread a text without identifying a specific source of
> concern in the sentence and minimal research efforts.
>
> ---
>
> Should I write in Korean or English?
>
> Both languages are accepted. When answering a question, we encourage
> you to answer in the language of the question, if you are able. Don't
> worry about making a few mistakes: other community members can help
> with corrections if you are not as strong in that language.
>
> On Korean SE, all tags should be in English unless there is no English
> equivalent for a concept; then Korean is accepted.

Comment: none of the text has been edited by me - I just blockquoted for ease of comparison with my version 2 (which I am in the middle of writing). I hope my intention will be clear once I've posted!

Comment: I like it - I hope my [version 2](http://meta.korean.stackexchange.com/questions/100/suggestions-to-fill-in-what-topics-can-i-ask-about-here-in-our-help-center/113#113) contains most of the points you added.

Comment: BTW, once we come up with something good, might it be good to translate it into Korean too?

Comment: Fair point about the Korean - maybe not needed.

Comment: I'd be interested to know what things you think I actually removed? Mostly I was just trying to condense it down by eliminating what I saw as a bit of repetition (including things that are already asked on the 'don't ask' page.) One thing I *did* remove was 'How to improve your Korean' from 'don't ask'; I agree that broad or completely opinion-based questions along those lines will be off-topic, but I think those concerns are to some extent dealt with on the [don't ask page](http://korean.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)and I'm not sure the community here sees learning techniques as off-topic.

Comment: It was a somewhat conscious decision to try to make it appear that there's more in the 'allowed' section than the not allowed section - after all, this is the *on-topic* page - but I tried to keep the substance of what you said, with the one exception I mentioned.

Comment: I guess it would be nice if this page *sounds* friendly and welcoming, but still "has teeth" for the reason you mentioned. however, there is very little that our community has *yet* deemed off-topic, so we don't want to overstep the mark. We can always change this page to quickly add anything that we come to decide is off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an initial stab at some on topic/off topic bullet points. I'm sure the wording can be improved.

> The following topics are welcomed here:
>
> - Grammar
> - Word choice and usage
> - Questions on Korean culture that are relevant to communication
> - Pronunciation
> - Linguistics and Etymology
> - Dialect differences
> - Spelling and punctuation
> - Orthography
>
> Please don't ask the following kinds of questions:
>
> - Translation and proofreading requests that do not relate to a specific question about the Korean language.
> - Simple reference questions that could be answered by consulting a resource such as a dictionary
> - Cultural questions that are not relevant to the Korean language

Comment: Wow, it looks great. I think we can start from here. (1) Please use English and Korean in asking questions, (2) Make a question as clear as possible with example sentences, otherwise, it could be put on hold as unclear. (3) Please don't ask a question that can generate only opinion-based answers like "How to improve Korean?" (Korean SE is not a discussion forum), (4) Naming, including naming programming variables/classes (as in English SE), (5)  Criticism, discussion, and analysis of Korean literature (as in English SE), (6) Character recognition is off-topic (as in Japanese SE).

Comment: I am leaving this for future edit or answer. (7) Request for a list (list all the colors in Korean type of question), (8) a question that could generate too many answers or too long an answer (too broad),

Comment: *personally* I would say feel free to add 1, 2, 5, 6. For 3) - did you mean that in the sense of "how to improve *my* Korean"?. I'm not sure I anticipated 4) being a problem - has it been, in other non-English language sites?

Comment: Yes, it has been a pretty annoying question on English Language and Usage. Some ask "What is the best name for my program?". I don't expect many questions, but we can never know. For (3), yes, "how to improve my Korean" such as "what should I study to improve my Korean?" or "Should I study grammar first? or How can I study Korean grammar" types. Let me edit the answer when I have time. Will duly let you know.

Comment: I agree those particular examples for 3) are likely to be both too opinion based and also too broad, but I think we need to be careful with how we talk about opinion based questions - basically due to what I mentioned [here](http://meta.korean.stackexchange.com/a/12/64)