# "General reference" questions

Tags: discussion

Although we haven't had much of a problem with off-topic questions of any kind being asked yet, we [wanted to be proactive](https://korean.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100/suggestions-to-fill-in-what-topics-can-i-ask-about-here-in-our-help-center) in starting [our on-topic page](https://korean.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). It contains a brief mention of general reference questions, as in the simplest cases it seemed obvious that our site shouldn't try to duplicate general reference resources. However, all ideas on on-topic/off-topic should come from the community - hence this question.

Comment: @Rathony I was giving it a day. Now closed.

Answer (score 3):

Simple questions on how to read and write 한글 that would be answered fully by a basic language tutorial or reference should be off-topic. (If a user has consulted such references but still has difficulty, they can still ask a question on their particular difficulty - e.g. [Why does Google Translate Pronounce '일' like hi'je?](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/1869/why-does-google-translate-pronounce-%ec%9d%bc-like-hije))

Although we're fine with questions on word usage, nuances of meaning, and word distinction, very simple questions like "what is the word for *tree* in Korean" should be off-topic (perhaps users asking such questions could be pointed to [this resource question](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/1815/what-is-a-good-digital-korean-english-dictionary)).