# How do you feel about questions on non-verbal communication?

Tags: discussion

We recently got a question over on Anime.SE that is about what appears to be about some sort of Korean hand gesture (depicted in a manhwa): [What do these money-related gestures mean?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/37116/)

Would this question be on-topic here? I'm thinking it might be worth migrating here, but seeing as this site is still in early beta, I don't want to dump things on you that you don't want.

(Precedent-wise: we have a couple of gestural-communication-related questions over on Japanese.SE, e.g. https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/27451/, and I would imagine that this is also true of other language SE sites.)

Comment: On the particular anime question source: if this is an (originally) Korean source i would guess it's fine to migrate. I think 'chisanbop' is relevant.

Comment: I have migrated the question to this site. It is now here: http://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/2069/what-do-these-money-related-gestures-mean

Answer (score 6):

We do have at least one gesture question:  [Crossed hand gesture](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/533/crossed-hand-gesture); we also have this (upvoted) suggestion that questions relating to non-verbal communication are fine: https://korean.meta.stackexchange.com/a/26/64. So in general, I think questions on non-verbal communication are fine until and unless we decide otherwise.

Comment: I agree that the question on the non-verbal gestures seems to be on topic.